# How can I replace the default camera app on windows phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10-mobile

How can I make my UWP camera app valid to replace the default (built in) camera app?

I have an application I have written for a client and they will use it on a bunch of devices at their business, they use the app to take photos with some additional metadata.

In windows phone 10 you can select multiple camera applications from the "Choose default camera" area of settings. But my camera application doesn't show up (I am assuming it is missing a capability set in the appxmanifest?)

How can I change my UWP application show it shows up in that list and becomes usable as the default camera app (launchable via the hardware camera button)

I do not need to validate the application for the windows store and I am using c#.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not possible for 3rd party devs. You need specific rights which only Microsoft can grant you to set the capability which is required for this.

However, I have no idea whether sideloading might have changed this. But I assume that MS isn't allowing sideloaded apps more rights than Store apps due to security constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's a shame that they limit the platform artificially like this, I was hoping that I could at least do it for an internal company's application. I don't really see the perceived security risk if it cannot be put on the store.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this is not possible for UWP apps on phones or tablets unless you are an OEM. This seems to be some stupid artificial restriction.